# Validate form loaded with Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that was loaded with Ajax. It is submitted without validation. I've found a way to manually add rules in case new fields are added to an existing form but how can I make validator parse the rules of the dynamically loaded form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is passed to your view (if you're using MVC) or what attributes it has however I made a simple loop for the 'jQuery Validation Plugin' which I use to provide client side validation for dynamic fields.

```
//Frontend
$(this.Form).validate();
$formItems = this.Form + ' ' + this.formGroupID;
$formGroup = $($formItems);

$formGroup.each(function () 
{
 $field = $(this).find('input');

 $isRequired = $($field).attr('aria-required');
 $type = $($field).attr('aria-type');

 if ($isRequired)
{$($field).rules("add", { required:true, });}

if ($type != null)
$($field).rules("add", { email:true });
});  

//Field for view
$field = array('attributes'=>array('class'=>'form-control', 'aria-required'=>false, 'aria-  type'=>'email', 'data-description'=>'Login Password'));
```

This is not the correct answer but please provide more insight to how you are passing data to your views.

[Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)